# How do I create a Gantt chart for repeating task using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, gantt-chart

I have a query that returns a bunch of quests and sub-quests for each player (or stages) in the quest, that I treat as sub-tasks.

The start and end timestamp are for each sub-task.

Here is what the data looks like

```
player_id    quest_id  stage_in_quest timestamp_start              timestamp_end
305       3         accepted       2013-02-18 09:19:06.254  2013-02-25 09:19:41.528 
305       3     time_up        2013-02-25 09:19:41.528  2013-02-26 23:12:49.268 
305       3         accepted       2013-02-26 23:12:49.268  2013-02-26 23:14:15.076 
305       3     bonus awarded   2013-02-26 23:14:15.076 2013-02-26 23:14:23.403 8.327
305       3         completed   2013-02-26 23:14:23.403
```

So you see quest 3 is picked up by the player 2 times, the first time unable to complete, and the second time completed. Again I have many rows with players doing same quest multiple times. I want to plot a gantt chart that shows repeating quests along the x-axis timestamp and with their stages. right now, in *iReport*, I use quest_id as Task expression, and  stage_in_quest as sub-task.

But the chart gets plotted with all only one set, overwriting over the next one. How do I get the bar(and their colored sequences) repeat for the same quest?

any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Try to use "stage_in_quest" field in "Series expression" of chart.

Comment: I used the stage_in_quest as a series expression, but it bundles up the start times for each repetition. So say, first time a quest began on 2/2/2013, and ended 2/3/2013. and second time the same task (or quest, in this case) began on 2/3 and ended on 2/4. The chart is plotted with one long bar with start times 2/2 and end-time 2/4, in one stretch. Any thoughts?